# How to make 4 pages spread

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5

I'm trying to setup a large presentation spread with 4 panels. They will be hung next to each other so it's important that I see all of them next to each other while I design the layout.

Facing pages allows you to see 2 pages next to each other. Is there some way to get the same effect with more than 2 pages?

Comment: Is the answer here still relevant in 2018? Doesn't seem to be working for me now

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set up your four page document the way you normally would. In a case like this, I'd probably turn off Facing Pages in the document setup dialog, but it doesn't really make a difference.

In the Pages panel flyout menu, turn off "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle." (This never makes sense to me, since the whole point is to let me shuffle them, but they mean "shuffle automatically" when you move a page from one spread to another.)

Drag a page thumbnail to the right edge of the first page, until you see a black "]" appear at that right edge. Let go. The page thumbnails will snap together, and in the document window you'll see the two pages side by side, like a regular spread.

Repeat for the remaining two panels to make a "four page spread" in the main document window.

One of InDesign's neater little tricks, imho.

Comment: +1 for the answer. +another1 for *finally* explaining WTF Adobe was thinking when they labeled that function "Allow pages to shuffle," because it is the least intuitive name I could possibly conceive of.

Comment: LOL! It still ALWAYS gives me a slight moment of confusion, every time I use it. I'd call it *counter*-intuitive, myself. I suspect it's one of those points where what makes complete sense to an engineer working with the code completely baffles the user.

Comment: I just keep checking and unchecking that (and Allow document to shuffle) until it does what I want.

Comment: this is great! i saw that 'allow pages to shuffle' i thought i want it ON to do what i wanted to do, i never guessed i would actually want it OFF.

Comment: Yeah, THAT would make sense, wouldn't it? Never makes sense to me, but there it is.

Comment: Thanks Alan, worked well, then i realised i would really love a 50mm gap between the sheets since they won't actually touch when they get pinned up. Posted a new question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2496/how-to-put-a-gap-between-pages-in-a-spread-in-indesign

Comment: And I answered it. Not a very satisfactory one, perhaps, but maybe better than nothing.

Comment: Is this still true? I can't sem to get the black ] in CC 2018