# How to put a 'gap' between pages in a spread in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

*(sort of step 2 for [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2494/how-to-put-4-pages-next-to-each-other-in-indesign) but also technically a new question in its own right)*

I have 4 pages side by side in a spread and i would like to put a small gap between them, to simulate how they will be pinned up on the wall. At the moment the pages touch edge to edge.

Is it possible to have these pages side by side but with a gap between them?

again; using Indesign CS5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this answer is *super* late, and I doubt anyone will see it. But I've just figured out how to do this, so I thought I'd share.

If I'm understanding you correctly, here are the steps:

1. Select the Page Tool (third from the top of the toolbar)
2. Select one of your pages on the artboard
3. Check the "Objects Move with Page" box at the top of the screen
4. Click and drag that page away from the others

It may be too late for you, but maybe this will help someone else. :)

Comment: maybe that thread's too old... i can't try your trick as InDesign allows me to move the pages up and down only...

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way the InDesign DOM works, what you see and can target in the document window is a spread (even if it's only one page). The document is a container for spreads, and a spread is a container for pages, which are containers for various objects, and so on.

The way InDesign displays a spread is as a continuous item. There's no provision in the program to pull that view apart, even though you intend four separate panels in the end.

One (somewhat kludgy) way you could get this effect, if you have the monitor space, is to open three more windows (Window > Arrange > New Window) and put a different panel in each window. Window > Arrange > Float All in Windows might work better once you have the four open.

Comment: Cheers Alan, I hoped to have objects spanning multiple pages so unlikely multiple documents will work. another work-around could be a single 'page' that is 4 panels wide + the gaps between and then use gutters. I just hoped there might be a more elegant method.

Comment: Not multiple documents, just multiple windows. "New Window" opens the same document in an additional window (very handy when you want to have a zoomed-in view for detail work while still being able to see the "grand overview" -- I use it a lot in Photoshop, occasionally in InDesign).

Comment: Oh that might work, cheers

Answer (score 2):

**File > Document Setup** - uncheck the box "**Facing Pages**". All pages will appear individually.

Simply return to **Document Setup** and check the box to return all your pages to appear as spreads (side by side sheets).

Answer (score 1):

To Add a Gap between spreads (so you can add bleed on all 4 sides) I used Stephanie's answer from 2011 and it worked like a charm. Just be sure that you've got everything unlocked on the spread, and watch to be sure items on master pages are moving (like page numbers). Use your arrows to move side to side. You can see when you've got the right bleed amount, as you'll see a red line appear in the middle that designates the bleed setting. Here were her steps:

Select the Page Tool (third from the top of the toolbar)
Select one of your pages on the artboard
Check the "Objects Move with Page" box at the top of the screen
Click and drag that page away from the others
It may be too late for you, but maybe this will help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your original document with a wider page size (say 5mm/.125 inches wider) than what your final page will be. Then go in to each page with the Page Tool and resize the width to the final size. It should leave a gap -- we just tried it here and it worked! And, the gap was still there when we closed and re-opened the file. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video that I found to be extremely helpful in walking through how to do this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzL_NHhn0w0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112942)