# Converting InDesign CS6 document to printer spreads using print booklet

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs6

I am trying to create a press ready PDF for a 16 page InDesign document using Print Booklet. I see the Print Booklet preview and everything looks fine, spreads are correct, etc. However, when I run the resulting postscript file through Distiller, the right side of the first spread (i.e. the front cover) is blank. If I simply export to PDF, the cover turns out fine, but of course the pages are not in printer spreads.

I get no error messages when preflighting the document in InDesign.

Also, blank spreads are not printing, even though I have checked the box to print blank spreads.

My Distiller version is X. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/indesign-spread-pagination -- The last paragraph of the accepted answer will help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what's going on in your document but I have a theory from my previous experience:

This situation can happen if you place an uncropped spread-sized box or file on your first or last page. When InDesign creates a booklet imposition it sometimes may overlay the front cover with the uncropped part of the back cover.

If my theory has anything to do with the reality of your document, the solution is to make sure the contents of both first and last page are properly cropped to the page (bleed) size and nothing sticks outside.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went back and double-checked but everything is within the bleed on all pages. There still would be the mystery of why the blank spreads were being left out also...even though the preview of the booklet was perfect. Which leads me to believe it was something within Distiller, but after trying many different settings, with the same results, I gave up and let the printer deal with it. Apparently they had no problem!