# 'Printers page' PDF layout in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm doing the layout (first time) for a friends charity magazine, last minute as the usual girl quit just before it was due, so panic time there.

I'd saved the individual pages (as I'd been asked) as individual press quality PDFs - now the printer has asked if I can save again as a pdf but  as either printers spread or
printers pages Apparently that gives it to them as opposite pages ie front/back cover, second page, second last page, etc. I've never come across this before (I'm not usually involved in this type of thing so it's a *big* learning curve here.)
I've been looking around the help files but can't see the answer - Can someone here show me the way?

I'm on a Mac with Web Design Premium CS6.
Pages were laid out in InDesign with photos etc in Photoshop or Illustrator.

Comment: When you view it in InDesign are the pages in a spread format?

Comment: There's no reason the printer can't do the imposition for you. It just might cost your employer a small amount more. Though I've never been charged for that service by a printer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InDesign Spread Pagination](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5737/indesign-spread-pagination)

Answer (score 1):

Choose File > Print Booklet.
If a printer preset has the settings you want, choose it in the Print Preset menu.
To use the print settings (as they appear in the Print dialog box) of the current document, choose Current Document Settings from the Print Preset menu.

If you don’t want the entire document to be imposed, select Range in the Setup area and specify which pages to include in the imposition.
Use hyphens to separate consecutive page numbers, and commas for nonadjacent page numbers. For example, typing 3-7, 16 imposes pages 3 through 7 and 16.

Note: If you have divided the document into sections of page numbers, you should enter section page numbers (such as Sec2:11) in the Range field.
To change settings such as printer’s marks and color output, click Print Settings. Using the options on the left, change settings as needed, and then click OK.
In the Print Booklet dialog box, specify other booklet setup options as appropriate, and then click Print.
Note: The number of pages in a booklet is always a multiple of four. If you are printing to a PDF printer, blank pages are inserted in the PDF to create the booklet.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-704ba.html

Comment: In regards to those nasty little section numbers, you also have the option to use absolute numbers by including a `+` and leave the range open ended with the `-`. In other words, `+2-` will output the doc from the second page to the end.

Comment: Many thanks guys, you've helped heaps and I've just got sorted with the printer.